# Is there any way to use same epoll thread for spring webflux and lettuce

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, lettuce

Spring webflux and lettuce both use netty. As a result, both create epoll thread.

We know, to minimize thread context switch cost it's better to create the available number of processor's equivalent epoll thread. But when we are using those in the same application both create separate netty epoll thread. As a result, epoll thread number = ( 2 * available processor)

So, is there any way to use the same epoll thread for both of them?